# How to say this more briefly?

Tags: sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

> Jim is able/capable to do A.
>
> Jim is able/capable to do B.

Now I want to say, in a more brief way, that *Jim is as able/capable to do A as he is to do B.*

Which of the following is better? Or maybe an even better way you may suggest?

Jim is equally able/capable to do A and B.

Jim is able/capable equally to do A and B.

Comment: *Jim **can** swim **and** skate*, for example, is pretty direct and to the point.

Answer (score 3):

We usually say

> Jim is able **to do** A.
>   Jim is capable **of doing** B.

My suggestions are

> Jim is equally able to do A and B.
>   Jim is capable of doing both A and B.
>   Jim is just as capable of doing A as B.
>   Jim can do A just as well as B.